# Meteor 'click' event, wait for subscriptions during event

Tags: events, meteor, subscription

Is there a way for a click event to wait for subscriptions to be ready before moving on to next line within that event?

I have a nested selector for choosing nested categories. When I click the category I want to dive further into, I want the category list to slide left, then have the new category list to fade in once the subscription has become ready. Here is my code for the event so far:

```
'click .nested-selector-item': function (event, template) {
  $('.nested-selector-page').toggle('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 250);

    /* do some stuff to update subscription */

    /* below needs to wait for subscription to change and be ready */

  $('.nested-selector-page').toggle('fade', 250);
},
```

I do not want to load all categories because there are tens of thousands of them.

Is this possible within template events?

Comment: Easiest way would be to set a Boolean reactive var to true on click. Then check in oncreated autorun if it's true and subscribe if. Then you can check if the subscription is ready immediately afterwards and then toggle the fade. I am on mobile so I can't really provide you an example right now

Comment: can u please show the code to update subscription?